# How can I work around the error "AttributeError: type object"

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am new to Python and got this error on my lattest project: Ive tryed to do an Discordmusic Bot

```
AttributeError: type object 'music' has no attribute 'setup'
```

And here is the whole code

Import and so on I left out

```
class music(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
```

There would be the commands and so on for the bot

There is the error

```
cogs = [music]
for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(client)

client.run("Token")
```

Comment: Look at you last lines of code: you are calling `cogs[i].setup(client)`, and knowing that `cogs=[music]`, you are just doing `music.setup(client)`, a function that isn't defined in the class mentioned on top.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not keen on the library you are using, but assuming that in the parent class there is a `setup()` method, the error is easy to fix:

You are calling music.setup(client), but music **is not an instance** of the class. Here goes a solution:

```
# This will call `__init__(self, client)`, so you need to provide a client.
cogs = [music(client)]
for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup()

client.run("Token")
```